# Evaluating function by replacing arguments

Tags: replacement

I have a function I want to evaluate by replacing its arguments with rule, however the result differs from when I manually enter the arguments,e.g.,

Given a functon

```
test[x_, y_, z_]:= Total@Log[DeleteCases[Chop[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}], 0]]
```

Evaluation through applying rule yields undesirable answer:

```
In[2]:= test[x, y, z] /. {x -> 0.5622814903606034, 
  y -> 0.21885925481969834, z -> 0.21885925481969834}
Out[2]= -41.0444 + 3.14159 I
```

Manually entering the arguments gives the right answer:

```
In[3]:= test[0.5622814903606034, 0.21885925481969834, 0.21885925481969834]
Out[3]= -3.61441
```

However I don't have the time to enter the variables by hand every time, how do I make the replacing method work?

Comment: define test as `test[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: @kglr But this doesn't change the false result of calculating to complex number through `replace`?

Comment: check`Trace[Log[DeleteCases[Chop[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}], 0]] /. {x -> 
    0.5622814903606034, y -> 0.21885925481969834, 
   z -> 0.21885925481969834}]` to see why we get `-41.0444 + 3.14159 I`

Comment: @kglr I believe fault lies in that the `Chop` and `DeleteCases` didn't kick into action as C.E. has alluded to since `ReplaceAll` doesn't have the `HoldAll` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll expand on kglr's comments. Consider what happens if you evaluate the function with `x`, `y`, `z` as its arguments:

```
test[x, y, z]
```

> `Log[x] + Log[y] + Log[1 - x - y - z] + Log[z]`

You get this expression back. `Log` and `Total` are still reflected in this, but `DeleteCases` and `Chop` are not there. Now we evaluate this function with numeric arguments:

```
test2[x_, y_, z_] := Total@Log[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}]
test2[0.5622814903606034, 0.21885925481969834, 0.21885925481969834]
```

> `-41.0444 + 3.14159 I`

This is the same answer you got from

```
test[0.5622814903606034, 0.21885925481969834, 0.21885925481969834]
```

Now, why do you get this when you use `/.` (`ReplaceAll`)? The reason for this is that arguments of functions (in the absence of a `HoldFirst`/`HoldAll` attribute) evaluate before the function itself.

```
ReplaceAll[
 test[x, y, z],
 {x -> 0.5622814903606034, y -> 0.21885925481969834, z -> 0.21885925481969834}
 ]
```

evaluates first `test[x,y,z]`, then `{x -> 0.56..., y -> 0.21..., z -> 0.21...}`, and then `ReplaceAll[evaluated arg1, evaluated arg2]`.

In other words, your `ReplaceAll` code starts by simplifying to:

```
ReplaceAll[
 Log[x] + Log[y] + Log[1 - x - y - z] + Log[z],
 {x -> 0.5622814903606034, y -> 0.21885925481969834, z -> 0.21885925481969834}
 ]
```

Consider using `With` instead, which does much the same thing as `ReplaceAll`, but has the `HoldAll` attribute and won't evaluate the function until after it has done the replacement:

```
With[
 {x = 0.5622814903606034, y = 0.21885925481969834, z = 0.21885925481969834},
 test[x, y, z]
 ]
```

> `-3.61441`

Defining `test` as

```
Clear[test]
test[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Total@Log[DeleteCases[Chop[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}], 0]]
```

works because now `test[x, y, z]` won't evaluate:

```
test[x, y, z]
```

> `test[x, y, z]`

Consequently, the evaluation will happen in the order that you expected because `ReplaceAll` will have to be evaluated before `test` can be.

Comment: So `ReplaceAll` doesn't have the `HoldAll` property, part of the function didn't work, much thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `Clear` the old definition of `test` before applying kglr's solution.

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)

Clear[test]

test[x_, y_, z_] := Total@Log[DeleteCases[Chop[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}], 0]]

test[x, y, z] /. {x -> 0.5622814903606034, y -> 0.21885925481969834, 
  z -> 0.21885925481969834}

(*  -41.0444 + 3.14159 I *)

test[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Total@Log[DeleteCases[Chop[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}], 0]]
```

Without clearing the old definition of `test`

```
test[x, y, z] /. {x -> 0.5622814903606034, y -> 0.21885925481969834, 
  z -> 0.21885925481969834}

(* -41.0444 + 3.14159 I *)
```

Now after using `Clear`

```
Clear[test]

test[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Total@Log[DeleteCases[Chop[{x, y, z, 1 - x - y - z}], 0]]

test[x, y, z] /. {x -> 0.5622814903606034, y -> 0.21885925481969834, 
  z -> 0.21885925481969834}

(* -3.61441 *)
```

Comment: So this works after all, but why though? The arguments are numerical to begin with?

Comment: The restrictions on the arguments are to keep the function from evaluating until the arguments are numerical, i.e., until after the replacements are made so that the `Chop` and `DeleteCases` have a chance to work.

Comment: Ah I forgot, sorry, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @L.Quen Did you read the end of my answer? I wrote about kglr's solution some hours before this answer was posted, although it was not present in my original answer so I'm not sure you read it... anyway, this answer spends more time on explaining how it works, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an alternative to using `With` as suggested by C.E., in order to allow batch evaluation. This is done by simply adding `HoldAll` and then `ReleaseHold`:

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[test[x, y, z]] /. {{x -> x1, y -> y1, z -> z1}...}]
```